# Grep multiple strings on large files

Tags: bash, unix, logging, grep, large-files

I have a large number of large log files (each log file is around 200mb and I have 200GB data in total).

Every 10 minutes, server writes to the log file about 10K parameters (with a timestamp). Out of each 10K parameters, I want to extract 100 of them to a new file.

First I used grep with 1 parameter, then `LC_ALL=C` made it a little bit faster, then I used fgrep it was also slightly faster. Then I used parallel

```
parallel -j 2 --pipe --block 20M
```

and finally, for every 200MB, I was able to extract 1 parameter in 5 seconds.

BUT.. when I pipe multiple parameters in one grep

```
parallel -j 2 --pipe --block 20M "egrep -n 'param1|param2|...|param100" < log.txt
```

then the time for grep operation increased linearly (it takes quite bit of minutes to grep 1 file now). (Note that I had to use egrep for multiple pipes, somehow grep didn't like them).

Is there a faster/better way to solve this problem?

Note that I don't need to use regex, because the patterns I am looking for are fixed. I just want to extract certain lines that includes a particular string.

Comment: tried you `fgrep -f pattern_file` ? Fgrep takes fixed strings from pattern_file. Don't tried it - but worth the try.

Comment: So when you peruse your log file, you don't want to do a full scan do you? Just the last writes should suffice? Do you have a pattern on timestamps? Can you limit your search to that? Is that an option?

Comment: @jm666 yes I also tried fgrep -f but it just improved with 0.03 seconds.

Comment: @JS웃 Yes, I have a pattern on timestamps but I want the full scan on those log files.

Answer (score 1):

In reflect to the above comments i done another test. Taked my file from `md5deep -rZ` command (size: 319MB). Randomly selected 100 md5 checksums (each 32chars long).

The

```
time egrep '100|fixed|strings' md5 >/dev/null
```

time

```
real    0m16.888s
user    0m16.714s
sys     0m0.172s
```

for the

```
time fgrep -f 100_lines_patt_file md5 >/dev/null
```

the time is

```
real    0m1.379s
user    0m1.220s
sys     0m0.158s
```

Nearly 15times faster as egrep.

So, when you get only 0.3 sec improvment betwen `egrep` and `fgrep` IMHO thats mean:

- your IO is to slow

The computing time for egrep is not slowed by processor or memory but IO and (IMHO) therefore you don't get any speed improvement with `fgrep`.

Comment: in my case, fgrep even takes more time than egrep for a single string. (pattern.txt has only 1 string). 

time parallel -j 2 --pipe --block 20M  "fgrep -f pattern.txt" < log1.txt > /dev/null

real 0m4.904s
user 0m9.074s
sys 0m2.398s

time parallel -j 2 --pipe --block 20M  "egrep -f pattern.txt" < log.txt > /dev/null

real 0m4.861s
user 0m8.955s
sys 0m2.394s

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I compressed the files into .gz format and used zgrep. It worked really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, compressing the log files into .gz format and using zgrep -E reduced the time dramatically. Also it didn't matter whether I searched for 1 pattern or multiple patterns in a single zgrep command, it just worked around ~1 second per 200MB file.

Comment: and how long does it take to compress the files? That can't be for free, ... or can it ;-? ... Good luck to all.

Comment: I already had those files gzipped, so I don't know for sure :)