# how to search for a file with pattern having white space in linux

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I am struggling hence need your help ( in linux ).

a) I have a file with two columns separated by a white space ( delimiter is " "). Infact, I run series of piped command on the command line which gives me output as mentioned above.

```
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
fff ggg
ccc nnn
fff kkk    # there are approx 20,000 such rows.
```

b)  I have lot of others file such as  file-1.txt, file-2. txt  , file-3.txt.

Problem:  I need to search for each line in the output mentioned in section a. above.    To illustrate, I want to run equivalent of:

```
grep 'aaa bbb' file-1 txt file-2.txt file-3 txt 
grep 'ccc ddd' file-1 txt file-2.txt file-3 txt
......
20,000 times
.......
```

But above command takes hell lot of time.

Question:

How do I use a single series of command to perform this operation.  Whenever I am running command ( as shown below), system only searches for individual words in the line i.e.  for aaa and bbb separately and gives me wrong output.

eg:

```
cat < filename > | cut -d "," -f1,2 | xargs -I {} sed '{}' file-1.txt
```

or using grep instead of sed....

NOTE: command before pipe is bringing the output in  space  as mentioned in the point a. above.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Write your initial output to a temp `file` and then use `grep -f file...` to load the search terms from that file. That will invoke grep **once** and prevent invoking grep 20000 times. (it will be a hell of a lot faster `:p`) `grep` is the proper tools for the job, not `sed`.

Comment: the files to search on are also organized in columns? are you trying to do a "join"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grep multiple strings on large files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475791/grep-multiple-strings-on-large-files)

Comment: If you are doing that repeatedly, you might consider [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) - or even some real database like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/): either adapt the program creating these files to write into an Sqlite -or Postgresql- database, or write a specific program or script to make one.

Answer (score 3):

Store all the patterns (`aaa bbb` etc.) to a file (`patterns.txt`), one per line, and then

```
grep -f patterns.txt file-*.txt
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Hin's answer, you can produce the patterns and do the grep search in one line using bash's process substitution:

```
grep -F -f <(cut -d, -f1,2 filename) file-*.txt
```

I'm assuming the patterns you're producing are fixed strings, not regular expressions, hence the `-F` option